# Predicting time series data with python

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm starting with machine learning and so far have only tested scikit-learn but I couldn't find the right algorithm or an example similar to my problem.

I have a time series showing where an event happened. The location of the event is identified with an integer between 1 and 25 ( including ). At a certain date, an event cannot happen at the same place twice and it always happens in 5 places.

My data looks like this:

```
2015-01-01,1,3,5,8,9,10
2015-01-03,23,16,3,5,9
2015-01-05,22,16,6,13,11
```

The first column is the date and the others are the places. Dates aren't included if nothing happened.

Do you have any recommendations on which algorithm should I take a look to try to predict the numbers ( places ) in the next time series?

An algorithm that is available in a Python library like scikit-learn would be perfect!

Comment: maybe you could use pandas library for this csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea would to treat it as a multi-class problem. You can imagine this as your target `y` having 25 rows (actually 24 but forget about it for now) where each column is 1 or 0 representing wether the event happened or not.

As predictors for your `X` you can chose some lagged average or the last lets say `3` observations. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852199/python-machine-learning-algorithm-to-recognize-known-events/27852335#27852335) for more details.

Some code:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

s="""
2015-01-01,1,2,3
2015-01-03,1,2,4
2015-01-05,1,2,4
2015-01-07,1,4,3
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), index_col=0, parse_dates=True, header=None)

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
labels = mlb.fit_transform(df.values)
labels
[[1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 0 1]
 [1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 1]]
```

We have 4 classes and 4 examples so we get a 4x4 matrix. Columns represent classes/locations and rows are events.

Now we will use the first 3 observations to predict the fourth one:

```
X = labels[:-1]   
[[1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 0 1]
 [1 1 0 1]]
```

We get 4 classes and 3 observations. We need to make it a vector because this is only a sample:

```
>>> X.flatten()
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Each column here is a feature/predictor that can be interpreted in the following way: A 1 in the first column means that class one was present 3 days a go. A 0 in the 7th column means that class 3 was not present in 2 days ago, and so on.

So now we have one sample/event (one row of the final `X` matrix) and the corresponding label(one row of the target `y`):

```
>>> labels[-1]
[1 0 1 1]
```

If you follow this procedure you will be able to get a training set that can be fed to a classifier.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d80d2a571b7b53c518d2 How should my predictors look like?

Comment: Thanks for the code but it looks like enc is not defined. Besides that I understand your explanation. I'm just not sure how I should call RandomForestClassifier.fit(training, labels). Should I call it for each place history? Example: [1,1,1,1] for place 1, [1,1,1,0] for place 2 etc.

Comment: That line was a mistake, see my edit. Why I explained is how to obtain a row in `X` and `y`. You should do the same for each place in history and in this case you will get `n_events - window_size` rows like the one I have just shown. Then you can do `RandomForestClassifier.fit(X, y)`.

Comment: Got it! Took sometime to understand but I guess I got. Thanks a lot for your explanation.